# How can I extract URLs from a huge one line text file?

Tags: url, text, copy, notepad++, line

I have a text file that I want to extract links from.

The problem is that the text file is only one line with a lot of links!

Or that when I open it in Notepad it shows it in a lot files but not organized.

Sample text:

> [{"participants": ["minanageh379", "xcsadc"], "conversation":
>   [{"sender": "minanageh379", "created_at":
>   "2019-04-12T12:51:56.560361+00:00", "media":
>   "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2"},
>   {"sender": "minanageh379", "created_at":
>   "2019-04-12T12:51:51.923138+00:00", "text": "sd"}, {"sender":
>   "minanageh379", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:51:41.689524+00:00",
>   "text": "sdsa"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at":
>   "2019-04-12T12:50:57.283147+00:00", "text": "‍❤️‍‍"}, {"sender":
>   "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:35.248517+00:00", "text":
>   "czx"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at":
>   "2019-04-12T12:39:34.352752+00:00", "text": "dsad"}, {"sender":
>   "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:30.889023+00:00", "media":
>   "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e985406d6eac06bb11c2d6052c1821a2/5D508106/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/56218099_577906226037731_8663356006073884002_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwMjk0MjA1ODQxNzYzNjM1OTI1ODMwMjYzMTExNjg%3D.2"},
>   {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:38:54.823472+00:00",
>   "text": "hi hi hi"}]}]

expected result

> https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2
>
> https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e985406d6eac06bb11c2d6052c1821a2/5D508106/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/56218099_577906226037731_8663356006073884002_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwMjk0MjA1ODQxNzYzNjM1OTI1ODMwMjYzMTExNjg%3D.2

the updated one

```
{"sender": "ncccy", "created_at": "2019-01-28T17:09:29.216184+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/57c43d748xcasc1abf58c890c5a6df042/5D199AE8/t51.2885-15/e15/p480x480/49913269_2181952555454636_8892094125900591548_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg1NjgsdasdAwNjgxNTk1OTY0OTIwMTA1NTMzNDQ%3D.2"},
```

Comment: Try using regular expression - [What is regular expression?](https://www.guru99.com/php-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: I agree with the above comment +1.  This is a job well suited to regex, most likely outside of NPP.

Comment: fine ... but which one should i use to match 
links like this ?


"https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/24dsadasdsd3b541a04b732d8bf/5D1E0B08/t51.2885-15/e35/27878451_164462087677179_3678721784892358656_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=MjgwMDQzMTEzNDIwMzE1NTExNzA5OTE4MjU2NjcyMjc2NDg%3D.2"

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55652850/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: @Toto Done ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

First of all, we are going to remove all characters that do not form part of a valid url plus quotes and spaces. That will remove emojis that seem to cause [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765464/strange-behaviour-with-boost-regex-and-emojis) with boost regexes on notepad++ on some circustances.

Our first replacement will be:

Search: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.~:\/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%"\s]`

Replace by: `(leave empty)`

<kbd>Replace all</kbd>

(That previous step may not be needed on future versiones on notepad++)

After the clean up, we do the following replacement:

Search: `(?i)(?:(?:(?!https?:).(?!https?:))*?"sender"\s*+:\s*+"([^"]*)"|\G)(?:.(?!"sender"\s*+:\s*+))*?(https?:.*?(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.~:\/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]|https?:))|.*`

Replacement: `(?{1}\n\n\1\t\2:(?{2}\t\2)`

<kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This should work even with "text" attributes that have several urls inside. The urls will be separated by tabulators.

So after applying the previous procedure to this data:

```
[{"participants": ["minanageh379", "xcsadc"], "conversation": [{"sender": "minanageh379", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:51:56.560361+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2   http://foo.barhttps://bar.foo"}, {"sender": "minanageh379", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:51:51.923138+00:00", "text": "sd"}, {"sender": "minanageh379", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:51:41.689524+00:00", "text": "sdsa"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:50:57.283147+00:00", "text": "‍❤️‍‍"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:35.248517+00:00", "text": "czx"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:34.352752+00:00", "text": "dsad"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:30.889023+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e985406d6eac06bb11c2d6052c1821a2/5D508106/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/56218099_577906226037731_8663356006073884002_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwMjk0MjA1ODQxNzYzNjM1OTI1ODMwMjYzMTExNjg%3D.2"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:38:54.823472+00:00", "text": "hi hi hi"}, {"sender": "no_media_no_text", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:38:54.823472+00:00"}, {"sender": "url_inside_text", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:38:54.823472+00:00", "text": "Hi! {check} this url: \"http://foo.bar\" another url: https://new.url.com/ yet another one: https://google.com/"}, {"sender": "ncccy", "created_at": "2019-01-28T17:09:29.216184+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/57c43d748xcasc1abf58c890c5a6df042/5D199AE8/t51.2885-15/e15/p480x480/49913269_2181952555454636_8892094125900591548_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg1NjgsdasdAwNjgxNTk1OTY0OTIwMTA1NTMzNDQ%3D.2"}, {"sender": "ny", "created_at": "2017-10-22T20:49:50.042588+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/19d94ea45c2102a0f7c97838ef546b93/5D14B3C3/t51.2885-15/e15/22708873_149637425772501_5029503881546039296_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjc4MzA3MDIyMTI3NDE3Njc3NTQxNTM1NTI2MjQyMjIyMDg%3D.2"}, {"sender": "xcsadc", "created_at": "2019-04-12T12:39:35.248517+00:00", "text": "czx"}]}]
```

We get:

```
minanageh379    https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2    http://foo.bar  https://bar.foo

xcsadc  https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e985406d6eac06bb11c2d6052c1821a2/5D508106/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/56218099_577906226037731_8663356006073884002_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwMjk0MjA1ODQxNzYzNjM1OTI1ODMwMjYzMTExNjg%3D.2

url_inside_text http://foo.bar  https://new.url.com/    https://google.com/

ncccy   https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/57c43d748xcasc1abf58c890c5a6df042/5D199AE8/t51.2885-15/e15/p480x480/49913269_2181952555454636_8892094125900591548_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg1NjgsdasdAwNjgxNTk1OTY0OTIwMTA1NTMzNDQ%3D.2

ny  https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/19d94ea45c2102a0f7c97838ef546b93/5D14B3C3/t51.2885-15/e15/22708873_149637425772501_5029503881546039296_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjc4MzA3MDIyMTI3NDE3Njc3NTQxNTM1NTI2MjQyMjIyMDg%3D.2
```

It may happen that you may get duplicated urls if those are duplicated on the original input (on same or different attributes).

Once processed you can remove duplicates with this regex:

Search: `(?i)\t(https?:\S++)(?=[^\n]+\1)`

Replace by: `(nothing)`

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>

Comment: This gives only one URL.

Comment: I'm seing the three urls on my regex101.com example

Comment: Yes, on regex101, but try it in Notepad++

Comment: Ok, I see there's a problem with the second url.

Comment: Fixed.  That was funny, I didn't expect that `\S` had problems trying to find those emoji characters. Using `.` instead of `[\s\S]` did the trick I usually recommend `[\s\S]` in notepad++ in order to avoid specifying the dotmatchall modifier

Comment: They also want the sender name before the URL. Read the whole discution under my answer. FYI: `. matches new line` is useless here, because there is only a single line in the file.

Comment: Unless somebody adds a new line by accident :-). It didn't hurt to have it. Ok, going to read new requirements

Comment: Doesn't work for all cases. Try it with the data from one of the demos in my answer.

Comment: @robinCTS Fixed! (I hope :-))

Comment: @robinCTS Edited! Hope It is better now :)

Comment: now the total line number is 329 
and by dividing it on 2 to remove the empty lines it's 164.5 
there is still 10.5 lines missing
 lol

Comment: Total line number? I expected you had the whole data in a single line, as you said on your question. Could you please upload the whole data on pastebin.com?

Comment: Yes I have the data on single line but after executing the regex  .every link gets on a new line . ... I wish  I could share it but it's private dm's

Comment: Check @robinCTS answer the first regex worked perfectly !

Comment: @minanageh, AFAIK, robinCTS first regex just fetches urls, without sender. Besides that, probably my regex and robin's 2 and 3 should return same data. Mine may add some empty lines at the end, but anyways... I think the main problem is that on the text attribute there may be multiple urls. Or perhaps we do some assumptions based on the limited data you posted. Perhaps there's some other json structure like multiple media attributes or urls inside media... who knows? If you could find a slice of the file that causes the problem that would be helpful

Comment: By the way, I believe that the correct way to check results is **not** divding the results by 2. Since probably there could be senders with more than 1 url. I think that in order to check resoults you should use Find in notepad++: `https?:` and select COUNT button

Comment: @minanageh, I have edited my answer to add a different procedure to process the data. Could you please try it and let me know the results?

Comment: although the link in this case gets duplicated ( the link isn't duplicated  in original DMs)
the links after the regex 
"msendr_lis https://www.mcdonalds.com/ae/ar-ae/full-menu/signature-collection.html https://www.mcdonalds.com/ae/ar-ae/full-menu/signature-collection.html"

the full text of these links 
https://pastebin.com/zMPkDrXs

it's not a problem :)
thanks so much for your help

Comment: @minanageh I'm glad it worked. There are duplicated urls because for a given entry there exists the same url twice (in your example the same urls was on a "text" attribute and also on a "link" attribute) Anyways you can remove duplicated urls with another step. I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G).*?"media": "(https://[^"]+)(?:(?!https:).)*`
- Replace with: `$1\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)            # beginning of line OR restart from last match position
.*?                 # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
"media": "          # literally
(                   # start group 1
  https://[^"]+     # https:// fllowed by 1 or more not double quote, the url
)                   # end group 1
(?:(?!https:).)*    # Tempered greedy token, make sure we haven't "https" after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1         # content of group 1, the URL
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2
https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e985406d6eac06bb11c2d6052c1821a2/5D508106/t51.2885-15/e15/s640x640/56218099_577906226037731_8663356006073884002_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwMjk0MjA1ODQxNzYzNjM1OTI1ODMwMjYzMTExNjg%3D.2
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: it works but what if we remove the 

*?"media":

from the expression  to make sure that we copy  all the links even the ones that are not media 

and is it possible to 
make put the sender name before the link ?

just like this 

minanageh379    https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/edddf95178aca7bf75930ab8698ee45b/5D45203B/t51.2885-15/fr/e15/s1080x1080/55823673_114448266206459_7321604432125975069_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjg2ODYwNDMxNzU3OTI1MTE1NTAxNjQ1NTk5MDkwOTMzNzY%3D.2

Comment: @minanageh: 1) you can remove `"media": ` but keep the `.*?`that is just before. 2) I'll have a look but it is a bit more complexe.

Comment: @minanageh: Have a try with: Find: `(?:^|\G).*?"sender": "([^"]+)".*?"(https://[^"]+)(?:(?!https:).)*`  Replace: `$1\t$2\n`

Comment: yup the sender expression  worked .

there is only one problem .. i tried extracting  the urls using an online site 


then i compared the results from your expression 

and 
the online site results 
https://i.ibb.co/gt9rdc4/image.png

the online site had 175 line while the notepad one had 144

Comment: the online site http://convertcsv.com/url-extractor.htm

.
 the 144 line 

https://ibb.co/XW13k0V

the 175  line
https://ibb.co/dK3TX7Q

Comment: @minanageh: Sorry but I've no time to compare these 2 images. Again, edit your question and add text where regex doesn't match.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/PM4Y5yS/image.png

"add text where regex doesn't match"

how can i do that ?

Comment: @minanageh: as Toto said, EDIT _your_ original question and add the text. Below the question is an `edit` link to make modifications.

Comment: I mean how can I get the text that's not effected by the regex

Comment: @minanageh: Compare your 2 images and find URLs that don't match but should do, then add the corresponding text in your question.

Comment: the problem is that the links orders are not even matched ....
they are missing not just not matching .

Comment: @minanageh: 1) Find an URL that is present in one image and absent from the other. 2) Find this URL in the original text. 3) Show, from original text, some context before and after the URL. 4) Edit your question. 5) We could be able to find why my regex doesn't match this URL. May be there is no sender or something else. Without this full example, it's impossible to see what go wrong.

Comment: @Toto  Done ...  i sorted the text before comparing them so i can find the difference easily .

Comment: @minanageh: This seems to work: Find: `(?:^|\G).*?"sender": "([^"]+)".*?"(https://[^"]+)(?:(?!https:|sender:).)*` Replace: `$1\t$2\n`

Comment: here is another one 


 {"sender": "ny", "created_at": "2017-10-22T20:49:50.042588+00:00", "media": "https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/19d94ea45c2102a0f7c97838ef546b93/5D14B3C3/t51.2885-15/e15/22708873_149637425772501_5029503881546039296_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com&ig_cache_key=Mjc4MzA3MDIyMTI3NDE3Njc3NTQxNTM1NTI2MjQyMjIyMDg%3D.2"},

Answer (score 0):

To extract just the links from the text file, do a regular expression Replace All using the following:

Find what:

```
.*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1\n\n
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/Ox1CDy/1)

Note that you need to have `Wrap around` checked in case the insertion point is not at the start of the text.

**Explanation:**

```
.*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)
|_||____________||_________________|
 |    ____|               |
 |   |    ________________|
 |   |   |
 |   |  [3] If there are no more following links, grab and discard the rest of the text
 |  [2] Store the link in $1 (starting with http and ending just before the first following")
[1] Grab and discard everything up 'til the first link (i.e. starting with http: or https:)
```

When using Replace All, the searching and replacing automatically continues until the regex fails to match, starting at the last point the data was matched up 'til, which in this case would be just before the double quote at the end of the current link if there are more links, or the end of the text otherwise.

---

To also extract the sender, use the following:

Find what:

```
.*?\{(?:([^"]*)"){4}[^{}]*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1 $2\n\n
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Ox1CDy/2)

**Explanation:**

<sub>Coming tomorrow</sub>

An alternative regex to do the same, but which is probably a little clearer is:

```
.*?"sender": "([^"]*)[^}]*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)
```

[Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/Ox1CDy/3)

**Explanation:**

```
.*?"sender": "([^"]*)[^}]*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)
|_||_________||_____||____||____________||_________________|
 |   ___|  ______|  ___|  _______|  _____________|
 |  |   __|  ______|  ___|  _______|
 |  |  |   _|   _____|  ___|
 |  |  |  |   _|  _____|
 |  |  |  |  |   |
 |  |  |  |  |  [6] If there are no more following links, grab and discard the rest of the text
 |  |  |  | [5] Store the link in $2 (starting with http and ending just before the first following")
 |  |  | [4] Grab and discard everything within the current set of braces up 'til the link
 |  | [3] Store the sender name in $1 
 | [2] Grab and discard "sender": " (i.e. up to the opening quote of the sender name)
[1] Grab and discard everything up 'til the first "sender" key which has an associated link
```

Step [1] works by initially starting at the beginning of the text and grabbing everything up to the first sender key, then grabbing the key via [2], grabbing the sender name in [3], and grabbing everything up to the associated link if it exists in [4]. If there is no associated link, [5] fails, and the regex backtracks to step [1] which continues grabbing everything after the first sender key up to the second sender key. This cycle is repeated until a sender key is found which has an associated link.

At this point, step [5] succeeds and then step [6] either grabs the rest of the text or nothing.

Finally, all the grabbed text is replaced by `$1 $2\n\n`, i.e. the sender name followed by a space, the link and then two newline characters.

This completes the first "replace". Since Replace All was selected, the whole process starts again, but with the text pointer either at the double quote at the end of the previously found link, or at the end of the text instead of at the start.

Comment: You may want to consider my new tests. I think your regexes may fail with braces and urls inside strings

Comment: .*?"sender": "([^"]*)[^}]*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)

this one gets me 165 lines only 

and this one too 
.*?\{(?:([^"]*)"){4}[^{}]*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)

......
this the one that worked perfectly with the output of 175 lines 
 
.*?(https?:[^"]+)(?(?!.*?https?:).*)

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers do exactly what you need, one thing to note is that the string you gave is a valid JSON string. You can verify that it's valid JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

If you're dealing with this string in a program, you may want to consider using a JSON parser for your language. [Here's the one for Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: Very useful info. However, this probably belongs in a comment rather than in an answer.

Comment: You may consider adding your own json parsing... If so, I wouldn't mind upvoting this answer

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative would be to parse the JSON data.

You can do this with javascript.

The following snipplet should work for parsing your data. It should even work with several urls inside the same `text` message:

```
yourJSON
[0].conversation
.filter(x => x.media !== undefined || x.text !== undefined && /https?:/i.test(x.text))
.map(x => {
    const tmp = x.text + ' ' + x.media;
    const urls = tmp.match(/https?:[\w\-.~:\/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*/g);
    return x.sender + ":\n" + urls.join("\n");
})
.join("\n\n");
```

You can paste that javascript (changing `yourJSON`with your data) into some browser that has some javascript console like Firefox or Chrome. In firefox you can launch the console with (Control + Shift + K) and in Chrome with (Control + Shift + I, then click 'console')

As an alternative, you may use this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj1toLux/) instead.

Edit the `javascript` square to use your data and then push the "Run" button.

Comment: the browser just hanged after pasting the data into 
 jsfiddle ..
:)

Comment: @minanageh could  you please share the whole data? Perhaps you could put it into a pastebin.com